# Grails 2.0, Atmosphere-Plugin and WebSockets

Tags: grails, websocket, atmosphere, grails-2.0

I am trying to get a sample WebSocket app running on grails 2.0 with jetty 7.5 in dev mode. I generated a simple AtmosphereHandler, but whenever I try to connect via a WebSocket I get the following error message:

E

```
rror 2011-11-24 17:18:32,075 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-4] ERROR [/jet2].[StratosphereServlet]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [StratosphereServlet] in context with path [/jet2] threw exception
Message: null
   Line | Method
->> 197 | upgrade         in org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   320 | acceptWebSocket in     ''
|    78 | service . . . . in org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketServlet
|    26 | doFilter        in org.grails.plugin.resource.DevModeSanityFilter
|   886 | runTask . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run             in     ''
^   619 | run . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Any suggestions as to what might be the rpoblem are highly appreciated. Best wishes Peter, Switzerland

Answer (score 0):

it seems the issue is with the Grails Plug In as I don't see Atmosphere classes in the stack trace. Thanks for filling the issue 
https://bitbucket.org/bgoetzmann/grails-atmosphere-plugin/issue/4/grails-20-atmosphere-and-websockets

Comment: I suppose it is in fact related to AtmosphereServlet since StratosphereServlet is a simple extension to AtmospohereServlet